# Why is JSON used in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb

Why is JSON-formatted data stored in MongoDB? Is that the only format supported in MongoDB? What are the advantages of using JSON for storing records in MongoDB? What is the benefit of using JSON in Mong DB over other formats?

Comment: JSON is well-defined, human-friendly, and commonly-understood .. on a technical level, any tree/hierarchical format would have sufficed.

Comment: MongoDB is web-scale and JSON is used on the web.

Comment: @user2864740 is XML format supported in MongoDB.

Comment: It's not JSON, it's [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: @Philipp (and kaduva) good points - I guess it's important to separate the interface and the actual storage/implementation.

Comment: still I didn't get a satisfiable answer

Comment: You've waited 10 minutes, kaduva. Have patience.

Comment: I think it would help this answer to clarify what this question relates to - e.g. is it about the model or storage implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Mongo uses BSON, that could represent the same things that JSON, but with less space.  "JSON" (that is like the representation for human beings) have some properties useful in a NoSQL database:

1. No need for a fixed schema. You could just add whatever you want and it will be correct JSON.
2. There are parsers available for almost any programming language out there.
3. The format is programmer friendly, not like some alternatives... I'm looking at you, XML ¬¬.
4. Mongo needs to understand the data, without forcing a "collection schema". You don't need information about the object to reason about it, if it uses JSON. For example, you could get the "title" or "age" for any JSON document, just find that field. With other formats (eg. protocol buffers) thats not possible. At least without a lot of code...
5. (Added) Because Mongo is a database they want to do queries fast. BSON/JSON is a format that can meet that requirement AND the others at the same time (easily implementable, allow reflectioning about data, parsing speed, no fixed schema, etc).
6. (Added) Mongo reuses a Javascript engine for their queries, so it have all the sense in the world to reuse JSON for object representation. BSON is a more compact representation for that format.

Comment: While it does use BSON and BSON does have a nice 1-1 with JSON, most of the points are meaningless as to why choose "JSON". E.g. 1) XML doesn't require a fixed schema; 2) there are many XML parsers; 3) use XML tools to make XML programmer-friendly; 4) schema's (or lack-of) are an independent issue. Basically, any dynamically-keyed hierarchical format *could* have been chosen on most (if not all) of those points - XML, JSON, YAML, etc.

Comment: (But back to the point of BSON being used - I think the "answer" to this question is to focus on *how* Mongo works with such hierarchical data, not how it is encoded or visualized.)

Comment: XML without the schema don't have any sense, its just a bunch of bytes waiting to get sense. Of course, there are successful XML databases out there, but there another point:

JSON/BSON format is simpler and the resulting documents are less verbose than XML documents.
XML documents tend to grow a lot (compared to JSON/BSON), and the parsers are difficult to write (correctly), and worse: they tend to be slower: If the data is longer and the parser logic is more complex then the CPU is going to have a bad time, with a lot of cache misses and branch misspredictions.

Comment: Those arguments do not hold. XML without a schema is not fundamentally different than JSON without a schema - both can encode a bunch of information "waiting to get sense". Also, XML (or rather, the DOM represented by XML) can also be stored in a binary representation (think BSON, but for XML). Furthermore, writing an XML *parser* is not fundamentally more complicated than writing a JSON parser - the actual XML grammar is very simple. I have no idea where the rest is going, especially since we both agree that it is an equivalent (BSON) mapping of an [JSON] object graph that is stored ..

Comment: .. that is to say, XML and JSON (or BSON if you will) are simply different *encodings* for hierarchical object-graphs. While they do differ in some fundamental ways - and there is a mismatch with the encoding of arrays and properties, for which it could be argued that JSON is "more natural" or "simpler" over a Map/Sequence object-graph - XML/BXML could have been used in place of JSON/BSON and represented the same information. (And again, I think all of this is  a largely irrelevant footnote to *how* MongoDB works with hierarchical data.)

Comment: Yep, there are some XML binary representations that are a real improvement (100x speedup in parsing)... And XML can represent more things than JSON (and BSON can store objects that JSON can't).
But we haven't considered that maybe the MongoDB team just likes more JSON than XML... They develop BSON seeking for a "lightweight...traversable...efficient" data representation. They control the BSON specification at their needs, so that could be a strong point to favoring their own format.

Comment: Ah, and I forgot that Mongo uses Javascript for queries... They reuse a Javascript engine, so it have all the sense in the world to use JSON for object representation... Maybe if Mongo uses Scheme/Lisp then they have used s-expressions, etc...

Comment: Now that's something I can agree on - MongoDB was *designed* with a simple [JSON] object-graph model in mind (and probably with some distaste for XML and a more complicated DOM). BSON merely being another encoding of the model, and JSON being the interchange format.